# Paginação perdendo os dados

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que tem paginação. Porém, quando clico em um número da paginação a página  recebo o erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: tipo_consulta in C:\xampp\htdocs\controle_gastos\tipoconsulta.php on line 37

**Código:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tipo de consulta</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1">

<tr>
<td>Descrição:</td> 
<td>Forma de pagamento:</td>
<td>Valor da parcela: </td>
<td>Quantidade de parcelas:</td>
<td>Numero da parcela:</td>
<td>Pago:</td>
<td>Cartão:</td>
<td>Numero do cart&atildeo:</td>
<td>Data de vencimento:</td>
</tr>


<?php

include "conecta_banco.php";

$idusu = $_SESSION["id"];
$consulta = $_POST["tipo_consulta"];

switch($consulta){

    case "exibe_tudo": 

        $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

        //seleciona todos os itens da tabela
        $sent_sql = "SELECT * FROM gastos WHERE usu_id = '$idusu'";
        $result = mysql_query($sent_sql);

        //conta o total de itens
        $total = mysql_num_rows($result);

        //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 20 itens
        $registros = 20;

        //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
        $numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

        //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
        $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros;

        //seleciona os itens por página
        $sent_sql = "SELECT * FROM gastos LIMIT $inicio,$registros";
        $result = mysql_query($sent_sql);
        $total = mysql_num_rows($result);



        while($tbl = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {            
            $descricao = $tbl["descricao_gasto"];
            $formapagamento = $tbl["moeda"];
            $valor = $tbl["valor_gasto"];
            $quantidade = $tbl["quant_parcela"];
            $numerodaparcela = $tbl["num_parcela"];
            $tapago = $tbl["pago"];
            $cartao = $tbl["cartao"];
            $numcartao= $tbl["num_cartao"];
            $datavencimento = $tbl["data_venc"];                                             




            /* Aqui converto a data que vem do mysql no formato y/m/d
             * para d/m/y */

            $datavencimentoconv = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($datavencimento));  



            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$descricao </td>";
            echo "<td>$formapagamento </td>";
            echo "<td>R$ $valor </td>";
            echo "<td>$quantidade </td>";
            echo "<td>$numerodaparcela</td>";
            echo "<td>$tapago</td>";
            echo "<td>$cartao </td>";
            echo "<td>$numcartao </td>";
            echo "<td>$datavencimentoconv </td>";
            echo "</tr>";

                    }          



        $sent_sql2 = "SELECT sum(valor_gasto) FROM gastos WHERE usu_id='$idusu'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sent_sql2);

        while($sum = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            $soma = $sum['sum(valor_gasto)'];

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Total: </td>";
            echo "<td>R$ $soma</td>";
            echo "</tr>";


        }

        //exibe a paginação
        for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) {
            echo "<a href='tipoconsulta.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a> ";

        }



       break;
}


?>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Lembrando que a variável `$consulta` pega o radio `tipo_consulta` de outra página.

Comment: Qual erro é retornado?

Comment: Aparece lá em cima a paginação normal,ai quando eu clico no numero da a seguinte mensagem:
Notice: Undefined index: tipo_consulta in C:\xampp\htdocs\controle_gastos\tipoconsulta.php on line 37

Comment: O erro ocorre porque você não passa nenhum parâmetro com o nome `tipo_consulta` na `URL`.

Comment: como assim?
não entendi.

Answer (score -1):

Fala meu caro, seguinte.
O erro que ocorre é que quando a página da consulta é carregada você passa o valor **tipo_consulta** via **POST** (enviado por um formulário), sendo assim quando faz a paginação essa requisição do tipo **POST** não existe mais o que ocasiona o erro. E como você usa o valor dele para demonstrar os resultados, ou terá que passar o valor via **GET** (URL, como vez com o número da página) ou setar ele em um **$_SESSION**. 
Não se esqueça de fazer a verificação se o **$_POST** existe ou não. Um exemplo:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Tipo de consulta</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1">

<tr>
<td>Descrição:</td> 
<td>Forma de pagamento:</td>
<td>Valor da parcela: </td>
<td>Quantidade de parcelas:</td>
<td>Numero da parcela:</td>
<td>Pago:</td>
<td>Cartão:</td>
<td>Numero do cart&atildeo:</td>
<td>Data de vencimento:</td>
</tr>


<?php

include "conecta_banco.php";

$idusu = $_SESSION["id"];
if( isset( $_POST["tipo_consulta"] ) ){
    $consulta = $_POST["tipo_consulta"];    
}elseif( isset( $_GET["tipo_consulta"] ) ){
    $consulta = $_GET["tipo_consulta"];
}


switch($consulta){

    case "exibe_tudo": 

        $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

        //seleciona todos os itens da tabela
        $sent_sql = "SELECT * FROM gastos WHERE usu_id = '$idusu'";
        $result = mysql_query($sent_sql);

        //conta o total de itens
        $total = mysql_num_rows($result);

        //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 20 itens
        $registros = 20;

        //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
        $numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

        //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
        $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros;

        //seleciona os itens por página
        $sent_sql = "SELECT * FROM gastos LIMIT $inicio,$registros";
        $result = mysql_query($sent_sql);
        $total = mysql_num_rows($result);



        while($tbl = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {            
            $descricao = $tbl["descricao_gasto"];
            $formapagamento = $tbl["moeda"];
            $valor = $tbl["valor_gasto"];
            $quantidade = $tbl["quant_parcela"];
            $numerodaparcela = $tbl["num_parcela"];
            $tapago = $tbl["pago"];
            $cartao = $tbl["cartao"];
            $numcartao= $tbl["num_cartao"];
            $datavencimento = $tbl["data_venc"];                                             




            /* Aqui converto a data que vem do mysql no formato y/m/d
             * para d/m/y */

            $datavencimentoconv = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($datavencimento));  



            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$descricao </td>";
            echo "<td>$formapagamento </td>";
            echo "<td>R$ $valor </td>";
            echo "<td>$quantidade </td>";
            echo "<td>$numerodaparcela</td>";
            echo "<td>$tapago</td>";
            echo "<td>$cartao </td>";
            echo "<td>$numcartao </td>";
            echo "<td>$datavencimentoconv </td>";
            echo "</tr>";

                    }          



        $sent_sql2 = "SELECT sum(valor_gasto) FROM gastos WHERE usu_id='$idusu'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sent_sql2);

        while($sum = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            $soma = $sum['sum(valor_gasto)'];

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Total: </td>";
            echo "<td>R$ $soma</td>";
            echo "</tr>";


        }

        //exibe a paginação
        for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) {
            echo "<a href='tipoconsulta.php?pagina=$i&tipo_consulta=$consulta'>".$i."</a> ";

        }



       break;
}


?>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Caso não funcione, comente por favor.

Comment: amigo tentei aqui,porém não funcionou.sou iniciante no php ainda.

Comment: como faço para setar ela via $_SESSION?

Comment: atribuir a $_SESSION["tipo_consulta"] igual vez com a variável $consulta. Mas nesse caso seria mais viável fazer via $_GET . Vou editar e postar o código com $_GET.

Comment: Olá,só tive tempo de testar hoje.
Tentei com o codigo que voçê me passou,porém o erro continua o mesmo,a primeira pagina funciona,porem quando clico em algum número da paginação da erro.

Comment: O erro que mostra é que não existe a variável tipo_consulta. Alguma coisa no seu código esta errada.